# How to find the cause of a memory leak?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, mono, blazor-webassembly

Let's assume I have a major memory leak in my .NET6 Blazor WASM App.
Afaik there are no profiling tools (yet).
How could I possibly find the root cause (gc-root) of the that memory leak?
Are there any hidden functions to get (and analyze) a heap-dump?

I already tried to get the Mono Log Profiler to work - without success unfortunately (see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41321)

Comment: have you found any useful tools?

Comment: nope...if you run into memory leaks with your Blazor WASM app, you are doomed I'm afraid